# How to serve Tensorflow model with multi-process uvloop server (Sanic)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, multiprocessing, tensorflow-serving, uvloop

I am having some issues running a Tensorflow model with a uvloop based server ([Sanic](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) even though it works fine with Flask. I think it has something to do with how Sanic spawns multiple processes? I say this because if I run Sanic with 1 worker (i.e., process) then the model gets served just fine. Although I do find it perplexing that I have deployed this same model with Flask+gunicorn using multiple workers and threads per worker.

The specific error I get is:

```
2019-10-22 18:05:39.062833: E tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/utils.cc:87] Failed to get device properties, error code: 3
2019-10-22 18:05:39.731232: F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:175] Check failed: err == cudaSuccess || err == cudaErrorInvalidValue Unexpected CUDA error: initialization error
```

I feel it’s at least partially related to https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2517

I've tried using `sess.as_default()`and `graph.as_default()`, before I make the call to the code that returns the prediction to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, even just some ideas to try since I've hit a wall and am kind of lost on how to proceed.